# Most pythonic way to offset a dataframe reference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This has been annoying me for a couple of days and I suspect there's an elegant solution. If I have a time series dataframe, is there an easy way to obtain the previous value to a particular date? So if I have:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
    index=['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02',
           '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04',
           '2018-01-05', '2018-01-08']
)
```

and the user passes, say, 2018-01-08, is there a simple way to obtain the value prior to that - so 5, rather than 6? ie, something similar to the excel OFFSET function.

I realize it can be done using the .get_loc() function, or even using the .truncate() function, but both of these seem slightly janky and I wonder if there's something simple I'm missing.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `shift`

```
test.shift().loc['2018-01-08']

0    5.0
Name: 2018-01-08, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**
Uset `get_loc` and subtract one

```
test.iloc[test.index.get_loc('2018-01-08') - 1]

0    5
Name: 2018-01-05, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks - .shift() seems like the neatest way here so I'll go with that.